# Как сделать заполнение промежного блока на максимальную высоту?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы данный блок [image: Блок у которого нужно как то изменить высоту]
мог растягиваться на максимально возможную высоту? (сейчас стоит height="70%")
И важное замечание: чтобы не превышало высоту родительского блока, и не "выбивало" нижестоящий блок под этим
(чтобы не было прокрутки).

Вот остальные данные: [image: Родительский блок]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.past_body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.h{
  height: 50px;
}

.fg-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="past_body">
  <div class="h">header</div>
  <div class="fg-1">content</div>
  <div class="h">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это и правда решает проблему)
Спасибо!